# failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Hv6ksS/trigger/

Tags: python, networking, triggers, configuration

I am getting following error while installing Trigger (https://trigger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) on CentOS. Trigger is a python framework for managing network configuration in firewall.

Collecting trigger
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/33/c5aa9c68f27ec6f9b21eb851a640b7dc2f9591894be6c043f13dbab21fb0/trigger-1.6.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
error in trigger setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Hv6ksS/trigger/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.